# connection problems with mongodb in r

Tags: r, mongodb, data-science

I am trying to connect with my mongodb account but when I try there are no suitable servers found 
this is the error

```
Error: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-00-b5p4s.mongodb.net:27017'] [connection refused calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-01-b5p4s.mongodb.net:27017'] [Failed to receive length header from server. calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-02-b5p4s.mongodb.net:27017']
```

this is my code

```
open=mongo("jordan.2", url="mongodb+srv://pelman08:<password>@cluster0-b5p4s.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", verbose = T)
```

Comment: Any update on this?